# Does reading an elastic document by _id count as a search for the `refresh_interval`

Tags: elasticsearch

In the write tuning section, Elastic recommends to [Increase the Refresh Interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_unset_or_increase_the_refresh_interval)

We're doing document ingestions where during ingestion we may do reads, essentially like,

```
GET /my-index/_doc/mydocumentid
```

that is, a read of the document by its _id, as opposed to a search.  Some descriptions suggest that the document id is just added to the Lucene index like other attributes.  Does this mean that the read by id would still reset the `refresh_interval` and force a `re-index` instead of allowing it to wait for the full `refresh_interval`?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a tricky one:

You are correct that a GET on an `_id` works right away (unlike a multi-document operation like a search, which need to wait for an explicit `?refresh` from you or the `refresh_interval`). But the underlying implementation changed twice:

1. Initially the GET on an `_id` read the data right from the translog, so it didn't need a refresh / the creation of a segment.
2. The code was complex and so we [changed it in 5.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20102) that it would be read from a segment, but a GET on an `_id` would automatically trigger the `_refresh`. So it looked the same on the outside and the code was simpler.
3. But for use-cases that did a lot of GETs on `_id` this was expensive, since it creates lots of tiny shards. So we [changed it back in 7.6](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/48843) to read again from the translog.

So if you are using a current version, it doesn't trigger a `_refresh`.

Comment: And, BTW, for anyone who cares, this code is also merged into opensearch 1.3.

Comment: That's a fork of the 7.10 codebase, so any version. Though no idea about any later changes there — the codebase is diverging quickly, so I'd be careful with any general assumptions of the current state.

Answer (score 0):

a get on the `_id` is not a search, so no